# Sorting counter dictionary to get list of keys and values

Tags: python, pie-chart

I have a list of values and i would like to plot the values and its frequency on a pie chart that is, i would like to plot only the two highest values on a piechart

```
Value_list = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`matplotlib`](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/) and `collections.Counter`,

```
value_list = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

most_common_2 = Counter(value_list).most_common(2) # taking most 2 common values

labels = []
values = []
for label, value in most_common_2:
    labels.append(label)
    values.append(value)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]